# Sync FullCalendar With Another FullCalendar Same Page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, fullcalendar

Using FullCalendar I am able to display 2 calendars on the same page.  Calendar1 has all the controls to switch views from Day, Week, Month, Year plus the arrows to go forward/backwards.  Calendar2 is a listMonth with no controls showing.  It works fine on load but I would like it to change when Calendar1 changes from month to month or year to year.

Is this possible?  I haven't found anything that would allow me to change the listMonth when the month/year changes on Calendar1.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,listYear'
    },
    views: {
        listYear: { buttonText: 'Year'}
    },
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: "CalendarData.ashx",
    eventColor: '#038ddd'
});

$('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
    },
    views: {
        listMonth: { buttonText: 'Month' }
    },
    defaultView: 'listMonth',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: "CalendarData.ashx",
    eventColor: '#038ddd'
});

});
```

Comment: Do https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewRender and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/changeView (or maybe https://fullcalendar.io/docs/gotoDate) give you a clue?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did find them but didn't think it was what I was looking for.  Using viewRender: function (view, element) { $('#calendar2').fullCalendar('gotoDate', $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('getDate'))},   changes the Month on calendar 2 whenever calendar 1 changes month/year...works great.  Thanks again.

Comment: NP. BTW you don't even need 'getDate' - `view.start` will contain the current start date for the newly rendered view. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

Comment: any solution for v4?

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to implement this recently to sync a grid and list view.  I came across this question, but the suggested comments no longer appear valid.  Here is a simple solution I used.

This is the simple html container for both calendars.

```
<div>
    <div id="calendarGrid"></div>
    <div id="calendarList"></div>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript code to hook into the "datesSet" method that triggers as the user navigates through the calendar and sets the date for the "other" calendar to keep it in sync, including a date comparison to prevent an infinite loop.

```
var calendarElGrid = document.getElementById('calendarGrid');
var calendarElList = document.getElementById('calendarList');

var calendarGrid = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElGrid, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    datesSet: function (info) {
        syncCalendar(calendarList, info.start);
    }
});
calendarGrid.render();

var calendarList = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElList, {
    initialView: 'listMonth',
    datesSet: function (info) {
        syncCalendar(calendarGrid, info.start);
    }
});
calendarList.render();

function syncCalendar(otherCalendar, startDate) {
    if (otherCalendar.getDate().toDateString() != startDate.toDateString()) {
        otherCalendar.gotoDate(startDate);
    }
}
```

Solution is based off of v6.0.2 documentation here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet